# Adding commits from another repo to git

Tags: git

I have merged multiple repos into one monorepo using

```
git subtree add -P myMonorepo/someWorkspace git@bitbucket.org:some/project.git master
```

And have been working on the project for a few weeks, while my colleagues committed to the original repos. How do I add the new commits from my colleagues to the monorepo?

Comment: `git subtree pull` ?

Answer (score 0):

Text patch files are a convenient way to transfer the deltas.
They are easily inspected so it's a rather transparent approach.
Metadata like commit messages will be preserved.

In some/project.git
[execute](https://linux.die.net/man/1/git-format-patch):

```
$ git format-patch ...
```

It accepts args to filter by hash or date range, as you prefer.

Now you have all "recent" edits.
Transfer the generated patch files to a temp dir
where someWorkspace can
[execute](https://linux.die.net/man/1/git-am):

```
$ git am /tmp/*.patch
```

Commit, and you're done.

Comment: This doesn’t seem directly relevant?

Comment: Using format-patch + am is quite a versatile, low risk approach. It splits the problem into read + write parts, and crucially it allows verifying before a change. The OP either didn’t know which of git’s thousand commands was relevant, or was frightened of an accidental bad result. Having this generic read + write technique in your toolbox addresses both concerns across a wide range of novel situations.